# Configuring resource bundle in jsf2.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have problem referring to resource values from .properties file in xhtml file

I get following message :

```
Jul 23, 2012 8:33:27 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl getMimeType
WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file hello.  To resolve this,
add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
```

Here is my faces-config.xml

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>resources.resources</base-name>
            <var>resource</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Here is my test page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view>
    <h:head>
        <h:outputText value="Header" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="#{resource.hello}" />
            <h:outputText value="Body" />
            <br />
            <p:spinner />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

What could be wrong ?

EDIT:

Not sure if it matters , i use Primefaces-3.3.1

Thanks!

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that this problem occurred after you added and used the `<resource-bundle>`? The very same problem should still manifest if you don't use it. I bet that your XHTML file is named `hello.xhtml`. Which servletcontainer impl/version exactly are you using?

Comment: @BalusC , yes the problem still persists, and yes the file is named test.xhtml. i debugged and see FacesResourceBundleELResolver is not being called to resolve the properties.

Comment: The exception message suggests that it cannot resolve the mime type for the file `hello`. This is not the same as `test.xhtml`. Please revise your question and/or comment. Also please remove the resource bundle noise from the question/code as that's after all apparently not the cause of your concrete problem.

Comment: umm,i don't think i got you right.My test page is named as test.xhtml.

Comment: Within it i access #{resource.hello}, key value pair 'hello=Hello!' is defined in resources.properties file.

Comment: i mean if i don't use resource bundle it works. even now with resource bundle also the page loads showing the spinner component.The problem is just with displaying the external value form .properties file

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EL variable `#{resource}` is a reserved variable name which refers to the resource files in `/resources` folder which are used by `<h:outputStylesheet>`, `<h:outputScript>` and `<h:graphicImage>`. The EL variable `#{resource}` is usually only used in CSS files like so

```css
.someClass {
    background-image: url("#{resource['someLibrary:image/some.png']}");
}
```

Give it a different name.

```xml
<var>res</var>

<var>msg</var>

<var>text</var>

<var>i18n</var>

etc...
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Implicit EL objects](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, i will test it out when i able to access the source.